# preventing use of delete on base and derived classes while allowing use of new

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, derived-class, delete-operator

I am trying to prevent use of the `delete` operator on a base class or any that inherit from it, but allow use of `new`; another class takes ownership and deletes objects created this way.  I am trying to do it by overriding `operator delete` and marking it protected, and having deleter class as a friend.

```
#include <iostream>

class base {
  friend class deleter;
protected:
  static void operator delete(void *p);
};

class derived : public base {
};

class deleter {
public:
  void del(base *p) {
    delete p;
  }
};

auto main()->int {
  derived *derivedp = new derived();

  //delete derivedp;            // this must not be allowed

  deleter thisdeleter;
  thisdeleter.del(derivedp);    // this should succeed

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I get

> error: ‘static void base::operator delete(void*)’ is protected

when constructing with `new` ([live example here](http://ideone.com/ZMxUbY)), which seems counterintuitive - even if I explicitly declare new as public.  Is it possible to prevent destruction via delete while allowing construction with new in this way, and if not, what is the alternative?

One solution is to mark the destructor of every derived class as protected, but is there a less intrusive way I can do this with just operator delete in the base class?

Comment: Use the named-constructor-idiom, with a forwarder. (See `std::make_unique` for how to do it.)

Comment: Why not just make the destructor private?

Comment: `std::vector<derived>`...

Comment: @KerrekSB: making the destructor of the base class private creates an error in any non-defaulted constructors in defined classes

Comment: @Riot: Yeah, sorry - protected, if you want to inherit the property.

Answer (score 2):

The `delete` corresponding to the `new` has to be accessible too, because the *new expression* does not only consist of calling the new operator.

Instead, it's like this:

1. Call operator new.
2. Call the constructor.
3. If the constructor throws, call operator delete.

You can work around it by making *both* `protected`, and providing a `static` or free function for allocating them dynamically.

That has the advantage of only restricting dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about new having to delete if the constructor throws; presumably the same applies even if using the noexcept version.  I was really hoping for a solution that allows allocation using "new" instead of through a factory function, as that entails rewriting a lot of existing code, but this may have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the destructor protected and defaulted for all non-final classes...

Comment: If any derived classes have a non-defaulted constructor then this fails to prevent calls to delete on the derived pointers.

Comment: You probably mean "destructor"... But anyway, having a protected destructor prevents any deletion on a pointer to the instance of the class. If you do that for all non-final classes as suggested nobody can ever delete anything...

Comment: ... I mean without you being in control how and if stuff is deleted. Typically you will want to create instances to concrete classes via make_shared and expose them as shared_ptr of abstract base class...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - Deduplicator's answer was informative and helpful as to why what I intended is not possible, but the solution I ended up going for was to simply make the base **and all** derived classes' destructors protected.

This is more maintenance than a base-class only solution and it does not prevent a new derived class from being created with a non-protected destructor, but that can be prevented in other ways if needed.  This is much less maintenance than having to use a factory function at every point where `new` would have originally been used.